# Cakephp - get controller name and action from url when working in a different controller

Tags: cakephp, controller

I have a controller 'User' & action 'index', it it's view file with '$this->requestAction' I am calling a different controller & action. Like this:

`index.ctp`

```
//My html code
<?php echo $this->requestAction('anotherController/anotherAction'); ?>
//My html code
```

Now, the problem is in 'anotherController' & 'anotherAction', I want to get the requested Controller 'User' & Action 'index' with '$this->params' arrays, but it gives me 'anotherController' as current controller & 'anotherAction' as current action. Like

`anotherController.php`

```
public function anotherAction(){
  pr($this->params);
  //It gives me
  //['controller'] = anotherController
  //['action'] = anotherAction
  //I want to get the requested controller & action of url here
  //which should be 'Users' & 'index'
}
```

$_SERVER['REQUESTED_URI'] gives me the url but is there any better way to find out what is the Controller & Action here from URL?

Comment: It would be useful to show why you're using request action at all - typically using request action in a controller indicates poor application design. (e.g. calling code in a controller action that should be in a model).

Comment: Yes, it is true, I know it is a poor coding style, but I am not very expert in cake.
I was trying to generate the <title> in my layout depending on Controller & Action & parameters, that's why i'm calling requestAction in my layout file when I don't know which controller or action will be called, if you have any better idea, please, advice me. Thanks

Comment: In the absence of any code/details my advice is: Don't do that =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it as a parameter

```
$this->requestAction(
    array('controller' => 'anotherController', 'action' => 'anotherAction'),
    array('pass' => array('curentController','currentAction'))
);
```

You can then get the parameters as

```
$this->request->params['pass']
```

Syntax for requestAction: `requestAction(string $url, array $options)`